# Subtracting known chars or last 7 chars from form attribute using jquery

Tags: jquery

example

```
<form id='A_forward' name='A_forward' action='/some_url.php' method='POST'>
</form>
```

How can I using jquery get name of this form, subtract `'forward'` chars and alert `'A_'` ?

Comment: If you need to get a form by it's name/id (which is the same), you already know the name when you get the form. Unless you need to go through all forms on a page and get their name IF they start with A_, that would be a different question though.

Comment: I think I get what you want please see my last proposition ! hope this can help !

Comment: Thanks Anass it's working just fine, also thanks to others your posts are also useful thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to Delete 7 last char :

```
var name = $("form").attr("name");
var str = name.substring(0,name.length-7);
alert(str);
```

If 'forward' is fix :

```
var name = $("form").attr("name").replace('forward','');
alert(name );
```

Edit : Just Get what you want :)

```
console.log($("form"));
var name = $("form").attr("name").split('_');
alert(name[0]+'_');​
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b5eWc/)

Answer (score 1):

If you always need to remove 7 use:

```
var token = $("#A_forward").attr("name").substring(0, $("#A_forward").attr("name").length - 7);
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/BRJxh/

If the suffix will always be forward use:

```
var token = $("#A_forward").attr("name").substring(0, $("#A_forward").attr("name").indexOf("forward"));
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/BRJxh/1/

Answer (score 1):

This will take the name attribute value and alert the first two letters
(A bit verbose to explain it better)

```
var formname = $('#A_forward').attr('name');
var firstTwoChars = formname.substring(0,2);

alert(firstTwoChars)​;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var name = $('#A_forward').attr('name'); //read the name of the element

name.replace("forward", ""); //replace 'forward' with an Empty string

alert(name); //alert the name_prefix.
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
alert($("#A_forward").attr('name').substring(0,2));
```

Comment: Why? Please explain your answer.